# How to skip blank value and do calc based on specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this forum and would appreciate your assistance in regard to an excel sheet that I am have trouble with.

I need to create a VBA code for the following:

I Need to work out the Provision in `Column H3` based on the following formula and values listed in `Column G`. `Column F` is the column where the value might have blank rows, due to the fact that I am new I can't post a pic of the actual sheet:

`=IF(F3=0;(G3*(G5-F5)/G5);IF(F3>0;(G5-F5)))`

The problem is that `Column F` has spaces based on how many invoices a specific client has, what I need is some formula or VBA code that takes the blank values into account.

Any help will be appreciated

**Edit 1:** Sample Data

[image]

**Edit 2:** Code I currently have

```
Sub Check() 
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
Set rng1 = Range("F3:F100")

For Each cell In rng1
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1) - cell.Offset(0, 0)
    ElseIf cell.Value = 0 Then
        cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = ???????
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Herewith I added additional:

```
Sub Check()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long

Set rng1 = Range("F3:F100")
For Each cell In rng1
 If cell.Value > 0 Then
    cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1) - cell.Offset(0, 0)
  ElseIf cell.Value = 0 Then
    cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = `(cell.Offset(0, 1) * ((cell.Offset(2, 1) - cell.Offset(2, 0)) / cell.Offset(2, 1)))`
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

The problem shown in " " above does not give me the correct ratios

Comment: `due to the fact that I am new I can't post a pic of the actual sheet:`Just post the link of the picture and we'll take it from there.

Comment: Sorry for being slow, but do not know what you mean

Comment: Can I email the image directly to you

Comment: You upload the image in a free image hosting site like imgur.com then post the link here. No, I don't advise direct emails.

Comment: Hi, please find image at following URL http://imgur.com/zV6PjL3

Comment: I'm a little bit slow myself :p So what is your expected result? How will your sheet look like after? Or if `F3` is blank, what value do you want to use? Do you use `F5` value? So for `F6` you use `F8` value? Is that what you want?

Comment: and for F9 I use F17, but it is not always exact as it depens on how many invoices a customer has, I was thinking of using the word "Total " in say Column E and then Offset(0,1) to start doing the formula, this is what I have so far-

Comment: Sub Check();
    Dim rng1 As Range;
    Dim cell As Range;
    Dim i As Long;

    Set rng1 = Range("F3:F100");
    For Each cell In rng1;
     If cell.Value > 0 Then;
        cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1) - cell.Offset(0, 0);
      ElseIf cell.Value = 0 Then;
        cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = ???????;
      End If;
    Next;
End Sub;

Comment: Cool. It is clear enough at my end. I'll try to provide a solution to your problem. But hopefully, you can get some VBA guru out there to look into this as well. Btw, all additional relevant info which cannot be expressed in comments should be added to your question as I did for you. :D Next time, do it yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is non-VBA solution which I think is best.
I reduced your data to half, I got lazy typing which looks like below:

[image]

As you can see I have added a formula in `H3` which is based on your formula.
`=IF(F3<>"",G3-F3,G3*(INDIRECT("G$"&I3)-INDIRECT("F$"&I3))/INDIRECT("G$"&I3))`
The difference is I used `INDIRECT` to dynamically control the value of reference in `F` and `G`.

So basically, `F` and `G` reference is dependent on the value on `I`.
I used this formula in `I3` to get the correct row reference which are 5,8 and 17 respectively.
`=SMALL(IF(F3:F$17<>"",ROW(F3:F$17)),ROW(A$1))`
Above is an `Array Formula` entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Once entered properly, it will look like below:

[image]

As I've said, I just used portion of your data.You can adjust the Range Size to suit your needs.
You can make this into a template and just copy and paste values. Hope this helps you a bit.
I'm not saying that `VBA` is not an option, but this is the fastest I can come-up with ATM.:)

Comment: Hi Sorry but if I make use of your {=SMAL(IF(F3:F$17<>"";ROW(F3:F$17));ROW(A$1))} I get the following values in column I:
    I3 = 3.00 
    I4 = 4.00 
    I5 = 5.00 
    I6 = 6.00 
    I7 = 7.00 
    I8 = 8.00 
    I9 = 9.00 
    I10 = 10.00 
etc

Comment: Hi, I have tried your formulas backward, forwards, upside down and sideways it does not work, as a side note I do not know if this makes any difference but I use Excel 2010.

Comment: The more it should work, I'm using XL 2010 as well. Also, I don't know if it's a typo but it should be `=SMALL(IF(F3:F$17<>"";ROW(F3:F$17));ROW(A$1))`. Then press the ctrl+shift+enter combo.

Comment: Well, it should work but make sure that all the other cells in `F` are `Blank`. Meaning NO `Formula`, NO `Nothing`. That is the major difference I see in our screen shots. Please double check that only `F5`, `F8` and `F17` have value.

Comment: Thank you for the tip It seems that you were correct after cleaning the F column from - your code worked.